# Complexity class of recurrence equation

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, recurrence

It's been a while for me since my undergraduate class in algorithms. Could you please help me solving this recurrence equation?

```
T(0)=14
T(n)=4*T(n/2)+n^2 for n>0
```

I'm interested in an upper bound that is as low as possible.

Comment: What is the value n/2 when n is odd? Is 1/2==0?

Comment: We round it down, so yes 1/2=0.

Answer (score 1):

The exact solution of this equation is difficult to compute, but according to the master theorem, it's asymptotic bound is Θ(n<sup>2</sup> log n)

**EDIT 1:**

Actually it is possible to compute the exact solution, it is (for n > 0)

n<sup>2</sup>(228 log(2)+4 log (n)) / log(16)

(I obtained this solution by adding constants wherever possible to the master theorem solution and solving system of 5 equations with computer algebra application)

Answer (score 0):

When *n* is a power of 2, and *n > 0*, then the following expression gives the solution:

(57+log<sub>2</sub>n)n²